Completing the Square of Multivariable Function
I'm currently working on an optimization problem and struggling with this problem.
Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} $ and let $f_{\alpha} = 2x^2 +\frac{a}{2}y^2+xy-y$
a) For each $\alpha$, find the point satisfying 1st and 2nd-order conditions for a local minimum of $f_a$
b) Prove candidate you found in a) is actually a global minimum by completing the square
Hint: recall that function of the form $f(x)= \frac{1}{2} x \cdot Qx - b \cdot x$, where $Q$ is the positive definite square symmetric matrix, can be re-written in the form $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x - x^*) \cdot Q(x-x^*)-\frac{1}{2}x^* \cdot Qx^*,$ where $x^* = Q^{-1}b$.
--
I was able to do a) but I'm stuck on b), specifically the part where I need to complete the square. I'm very confused as to how I can "obtain" the matrix $Q$ from my original function form.

Hint: Play around with a 2-by-2 symmetric matrix $A$. How do its entries relate to the quadratic form $x^T Ax$? Then use the fact that symmetric matrices can be orthogonally diagonalized.
